# LXC using separate HDD/VOLUME

Tags: linux, lxc, mount-point, lxd

Is there some method how can I define the major device (hdd, volume, ..) for LXC container?

I have separated disks for each service/project which I want run inside LXC container. But I couldn't find the way how can I specify storage for all files in the container. I mean whole container (/, /home, /var,...)

So finally I want to create this association
1 service/project == 1 container == 1 HDD

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create storage pools for each of your disks. Then, when you create a LXD container, you can specify on which storage pool to be created in.

The commands to [create the storage pools](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/storage) are:

```
lxc storage create pool1 zfs source=/dev/sdb
lxc storage create pool2 zfs source=/dev/sdc
lxc storage create pool3 zfs source=/dev/sdd
```

The commands to launch containers on specific storage pools are:

```
lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 container1 --storage pool1
lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 container2 --storage pool2
lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 container3 --storage pool3
```

Do note that such a setup may not be very optimal. See whether you can use either ZFS, LVM, or btrfs. With any of them, you can specify to use all those disks together in some form of RAID. More at https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/storage

Comment: Thank you, I've solved it with profiles, so I've created btrfs storage pools mapped to my volumes. Because I am using hw raid and these disks are LVM ;)